# Oracle merge operation

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, merge

Let's assume the next two tables:

```
users (username, region, location, department, subdepartment)
```

and

```
structure (region, location, department, subdepartment)
```

At start, in the users table, each username appears in one record. I would like that if a username has the subdepartment column empty, to be automatically distributed to all subdepartement defined for that department in the structure table.

Meaning, instead of just one record in the users table, at the end there will be N records, where N represents the number of subdepartments defined in the structure table for the original region,location,department combination.

I've tried doing this with MERGE statement, but i can't figure it out. How could I do this ?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to insert users or select users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At speed you can do this:

```
insert into users
select 
   u.username, u.region, u.location, u.department, s.subdepartment
from users u join structure s 
   on (u.region=s.region and u.location=s.location and u.department = s.department)
where u.subdepartment is null;

delete from users where subdepartment is null;
```

but, for above, you must be sure that every department has subdepartments.(If it is not the case, you must do some simple PL/SQL)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table01 (
       code int,
       name varchar(50),
       old int
);

create table table02 (
       code int,
       name varchar(50),
       old int
);

insert into table01 values (1, 'A', 10);
insert into table01 values (9, 'B', 12);
insert into table01 values (3, 'C', 14);
insert into table01 values (4, 'D', 16);
insert into table01 values (5, 'E', 18);

insert into table02 values (1, 'AA', null);
insert into table02 values (2, 'BB', 123);
insert into table02 values (3, 'CC', null);
insert into table02 values (4, 'DD', null);
insert into table02 values (5, 'EE', null);

select * from table01 a order by 2;
select * from table02 a order by 2;

merge into table02 a using (
      select b.code, b.old from table01 b
) c on (
  a.code = c.code
)
when matched then update set a.old = c.old
;
```